# Run bash completion command for given command

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I am trying to create a bash completion for a custom function that I am creating:

```bash
gco() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        branch="$(git branch --all | fzf | tr -d '[:space:]')"
    else
        branch="$1"
    fi
    git checkout "$branch"
}
```

I want to be able to delegate the auto completion of my `gco` function to the auto completion for `git checkout`, so I tried adding this:

```bash
function _gco() {
    local curr_arg;
    curr_arg=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(git checkout)" -- $curr_arg ) );

}
complete -F _gco gco
```

However, when I type in `gco`  and then press tab, I get the following output:

```
$ gco 
1           different     into                respectively.    yours)
38          diverged,     merge               the
and         each,         origin/mybranch     to
branch      git           pull                (use
commits     have          remote              Your
```

I think the issue is with this line:

```
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(git checkout)" -- $curr_arg ) );
```

I don't know what the auto completion script is for `git checkout`, but I want to know if there is a way I can run the auto completion script for any arbitrary command without actually running said arbitrary command:

```
_run_auto_completion_script_for_command "git checkout"
```

Is there a way I can do this?